# Why do all process ranks become 0 after MPI_IRecv?

Tags: fortran, openmpi

I'm implementing a very simple non-blocking send-recv. However, I notice that after the MPI_Irecv(), all process ranks become 0. As shown by the code below, I try to print the rank before the MPI_Irecv() and the rank is still proper.
What did happen that change those ranks? and How can I repair it?

```
program send_async
  implicit none
  include 'mpif.h'

  integer :: process_rank, cluster_size, ierror, request, status
  integer, parameter :: MASTER_RANK = 0, ARR_SIZE = 10
  integer, allocatable :: arr(:), arr_p(:)
  integer :: i
  integer :: arr_p_size
  integer :: receiver_rank, start_idx, end_idx

  call MPI_INIT(ierror)
  call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, cluster_size, ierror)
  call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, process_rank, ierror)

  ! Initiate the whole array only in the master process
  if (MASTER_RANK == process_rank) then
    allocate(arr(ARR_SIZE))
    arr = [(i, i=1,ARR_SIZE)]
  end if

  ! Initiate partial array in each process (even the master)
  arr_p_size = ARR_SIZE/cluster_size
  allocate(arr_p(arr_p_size))
  ! Master send partial array even to itself
  if (MASTER_RANK == process_rank) then
    do receiver_rank = 0, cluster_size-1
      start_idx = receiver_rank*arr_p_size + 1
      end_idx = (receiver_rank+1)*arr_p_size
      call MPI_ISEND(arr(start_idx:end_idx), arr_p_size, MPI_INT, receiver_rank, &
        1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, request, ierror)
    end do
  end if

  print *, "Hi, I'm process of rank:", process_rank

  call MPI_IRECV(arr_p(1:arr_p_size), arr_p_size, MPI_INT, MASTER_RANK, 1, &
    MPI_COMM_WORLD, request, ierror)
  call MPI_WAIT(request, status, ierror)
  print *,"Hi I'm rank:",process_rank,"I have arr_p=",arr_p(:)

  call MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)
end program send_async
```

I use OpenMPI 4.0.3, and I compile the code with:

```
mpif90 -g -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -Wall -Werror send_async.f90 -o send_async
```

Comment: Although the linked question is about `mpi_recv`, your problem is exactly the same: you haven't declared `status` as an array for the call to `mpi_wait`.

Comment: Great! It totally answered the question. Thanks a lot! @francescalus

Comment: Can I strongly suggest you stop using include 'mpif.h' and instead have either "use mpi" or better "use mpi_f08" - the include file is not recommended nowadays, and the second module would have caught this problem at compile time (though note the datatypes it uses)

Comment: @IanBush hey thanks. All right, I didn't know it. I was just picking up fortran yesterday, and I'm really blind of the current best practices. The trending examples on Google search when I'm searching "mpi fortran tutorial" don't help either.

Comment: No worries - unfortunately quite a few MPI tutorials online are now a bit ancient.